# Partial order which forces finite intersections with sets not in an ultrafilter

Tags: set-theory, forcing

The following is from the Paper ,,Canonical models for fragments of the Axiom of Choice" written by Paul Larson and Jindrich Zapletal, in Claim 3.4:
Let $U$ be a nonprincipal ultrafilter on $\omega$ with empty intersection with $A$, where $A \subseteq \mathcal{P}(\omega)$ is an infinite $MAD$ family. Let $P$ be the usual $c.c.c.$ poset adding a set $\dot x_{gen} \subseteq \omega$ which has finite intersection with every set not in $U$.
We work with ZFC and the hypothesis, that Woodin cardinals exist.
My question now is: What is such an usual partial order $P$, that forces the above?

Comment: Is there any requirement on the relation between the generic filter and $A$?

Comment: I don't think so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given a family of co-infinite sets, $X$, we define the forcing that avoids all the sets in $X$, $\Bbb P_X$ as the collection of pairs $(p,S)$ such that:

1. $p\colon\omega\to 2$ is a partial function with finite domain.
2. $S\subseteq X$ is a finite family of sets.

Now define the order as follows: $(q,T)\leq(p,S)$ iff:

1. $p\subseteq q$,
2. $S\subseteq T$, and
3. for all $A\in S$, if $n\in (A\cap\operatorname{dom}(q))\setminus\operatorname{dom}(p)$, then $q(n)=0$.

In other words, once $A$ goes into the $S$ component, any further extension must avoid it.

Now it is easy to see that $\Bbb P_X$ is c.c.c. since any two conditions with the same stem (the $p$ coordinate) must be compatible and there are only countably many possible stems.

And if $g$ is the the generic subset given by the generic filter $G$, then for all $A\in X$, there is some condition $(p,S)\in G$ such that $A\in S$, and therefore any further extension beyond $p$ must force that $g\cap A$ is finite.

Comment: Why are two conditions with the same stem compatible?

Comment: Take the union of the $S$-component from both.

Comment: Oh and do you know if the forcing you described above has a name? Or are there examples you know where it is used?

Comment: I think that the term is "eventually different real".

Comment: Eventually different forcing is about functions (elements of $\omega^\omega$). In your case, you would have to add that if $n \notin A \cap \dots$ then $q(n)=1$ to truly call it eventually different forcing. This is usually called Mathias(-Prikry) forcing for the family $X$, denoted as $\mathbb{M}(X)$.

Answer (score 4):

One possible poset would be as follows: Let $\mathbb{P}=[\omega]^{<\omega}\times U$, and $(s,X)\ge (t,Y)$ if and only if

- $s\subseteq t$,
- $X\supseteq Y$, and
- $t\setminus \max s \subseteq X$.

Let $G$ be a $\mathbb{P}$-generic filter, and let $x_{gen}=\bigcup\{s\mid \exists X\in U: (s,X)\in G\}$. For each $Z\subseteq \omega$ that is not in $U$, consider
$$\mathcal{D}_Z = \{(s,X)\in\mathbb{P}\mid X\subseteq \omega\setminus Z\}.$$
Then we can see that $\mathcal{D}_Z$ is dense. Hence there is $s$ such that $(s,\omega\setminus Z)\in G$. From this, we can see that $x_{gen}\setminus \max s\subseteq \omega\setminus Z$. Especially, $x_{gen}\cap Z\subseteq \max s$.

---

It remains to show that $\mathbb{P}$ has c.c.c. Let $\{(s_\alpha,X_\alpha)\mid \alpha<\omega_1\}\subseteq \mathbb{P}$. Since $[\omega]^{<\omega}$ is countable, we may assume that $s_\alpha$ is constant with value $s$. Hence it suffices to show that $(U,\subseteq)$ satisfies c.c.c., and in fact, every pair of elements of $U$ is compatible.

Comment: Why is that c.c.c.? (It is, but you should perhaps say a few words on that.)

Comment: @Asaf I missed that condition. I will add its proof right now.

Comment: For what it's worth, your forcing is not quite "the standard forcing" in this context. It adds a pseudo intersection to the ultrafilter, which in this case turns out to be almost disjoint from all the non-positive sets. But in general you want to add an almost disjoint real. instead of one that is almost contained in all the reals that are in $U$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Where's the difference? Adding a pseudointersection of a filter $U$ is exactly adding a set that is almost disjoint from all sets in the dual ideal.